# Swiping non-native tokens using wagmi.js (USDT for USDC for example) Or asking for approval to access user non native assets

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web3js, cryptocurrency, ethers.js

I'm using wagmi.js to build a DEX,
I've successfully signed the user using METAMASK and swapped MATIC for any other token (polygon network).

but when I try to do the opposite it does not work (any other token on polygon network for MATIC), or any Token for any other token (USDT for USDC) For example.

when I tried doing this operation on other DEXs like DODO Dex, for example, the website prompts the user to approve access to their USDT token for instance and then it does the swapping.

So my question is how to do that? how to ask the user for their approval and swap non-native tokens using wagmi.js or any other library for that matter

_app.tsx file

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createClient, configureChains, chain, WagmiConfig } from 'wagmi';
import { publicProvider } from 'wagmi/providers/public';
// ... Rest of imports

const { provider, webSocketProvider } = configureChains([chain.polygon, chain.mainnet], [publicProvider()])
const client = createClient({
  provider,
  webSocketProvider,
  autoConnect: true
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps ) {
  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={client}>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
       {/* ... Rest of the App */}
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>

  );
};

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

I contact the DODO api with the params of the transaction.
and recive the price, data and the to address (DODO Router contract)

DexPage.tsx (snippit)

```
const [transactionData, setTransactionData] = useState<DodoAPIData | undefined>();

const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, sendTransaction, error, status } = useSendTransaction({
        request: {
            from: userAddress,
            to: transactionData ? transactionData!.to : "",
            value: (+fromTokenAmount).toFixed(fromTokenAmountDecimals).replace('.', ''),
            gasLimit: 500000,
            data: transactionData ? transactionData!.data : ""
        },
        mode: "prepared"
    } as any);

axios.get(dodoAPI, {
            params: {
                fromTokenAddress,
                fromTokenDecimals,
                toTokenAddress,
                toTokenDecimals,
                fromAmount,
                slippage: 1,
                userAddr: userAddress,
                chainId: 137,
                rpc: rpcUrl,
            }
        }).then((price) => {
            if (price.status !== 200) {
                // error
                return;
            }

            setTransactionData(price.data.data);
            // price.data.data contains the (to, data, and amount).
        })
            .catch((e) => {
               
                console.error(e);
            })
```